# Can a Ruby hash have an array inside its values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I need to display a list of products by the category. I was thinking of building a has with the category as it's key and the list of all products in that category as it's value. Is it possible to implement it this way?

Would this work?

```
@products = Product.all

@categories = @products.uniq.pluck(:category)
@products_by_category = Hash.new

@categories.each do |category|
  @products_by_category[:category] = Product.where(:category => category)
end
```

I used this to display the above hash in my vie:

```
<% @products_by_category.each do |key, value| %>
<th> <%= key %> <th>
  <% value.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= product.title %></td>
      <td><%= product.category %></td>
      <td><%= product.rating %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', product, :class => "btn btn-primary"%></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product), :class => "btn btn-primary" %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => "btn btn-primary" %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end%>
<% end %>
```

But in the display instead of category name I just get the string literal "category" (`<th> <%= key %> <th>` seems to print the string literal "category" instead of the value of the category)

Comment: Did you try it? :)

Comment: yes I did - I have updated my question with more comments on how I tried to use it and what results it gave me. Pls help!

Comment: You have a string 'category' because of `@products_by_category[:category]`. You're using symbol `:category` here instead of iterator variable `category`

Comment: That helped! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Vasilisa - would you be able to help me with another question of mine please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032436/how-to-update-created-by-field-in-scaffolding-generated-code - I have tagged you in that thread as well. Thanks much!

Comment: And what about my answer? :)

Comment: @Vasilisa - since I already had the code for hashes ready, I took your solution to use `@products_by_category[category]` instead of `@products_by_category[:category]` - that worked like a charm for me!

Comment: @Biju Vasilisa posted answer, please check, if worked then vote as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `@products_by_category[category]` instead of `@products_by_category[:category]` worked perfectly for me! Thanks to @Vasilisa for this solution!

Answer (score 1):

It should work, but there is a easier way

```
Product.all.group_by(&:category)
```